# Marketing API Facebook SDK

Tags: php, facebook-marketing-api, fbsdk

So Sorry but I'm quite new to Facebook SDK and API's. I tried to use the marketing API provided by Facebook itself.

In the quickstart, I followed all the steps provided by the site itself.

It will generate a sample code to use to my simple application.

I came accross an error in which I have to change a line as shown below and thought it might help other in the future.

If you came accross an error which told you about the deprecated v2.11 check below

From this

```
$fields = array(
);
$params = array(
   'name' => 'Test Catalog',
);
$product_catalog = (new Business($business_id))->createProductCatalog(
  $fields,
  $params
);
```

To This

```
$fields = array(
);
$params = array(
    'name' => 'Test Catalog',
);
$product_catalog = (new Business($business_id))->createOwnedProductCatalog(
   $fields,
   $params
);
```

Now, moving on to my problem.

The second part of the code is as shown below

```
$fields = array(
);
$params = array(
   'name' => 'Test Feed',
    'schedule' => array('interval' => 'DAILY','url' => 'https://developers.facebook.com/resources/dpa_product_catalog_sample_feed.csv','hour' => '22'),
);
echo json_encode((new ProductCatalog($product_catalog_id))->createProductFeed(
   $fields,
   $params
 )->getResponse()->getContent(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

I'm having problem with this part

```
)->getResponse()->getContent(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

The error im getting is this

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Call to undefined method FacebookAds\Object\ProductFeed::getResponse()
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
echo json_encode((new ProductCatalog($product_catalog_id))->createProductFeed(
   $fields,
   $params
 )->getResponse()->getContent(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

For this:

```
echo json_encode((new ProductCatalog($id))->createProductFeed(
  $fields,
  $params
)->exportAllData(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```